# Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start) option in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to deploy a **MVC Application** using **Code First** in **Visual Studio 2010**. I was able to find **Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)** checkbox in **visual studio 2012** under settings tab as shown:

[image]

I want to use the same option in **Visual Studio 2010**. Can anyone help me in finding it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install [Visual Studio 2010 Web Publish Updates](http://sedodream.com/2012/06/15/visualstudio2010webpublishupdates.aspx)

Have a look at [Code First Migrations : Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup (MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion Initializer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer)

Comment: Don't we have same checkbox option in visual studio 2010? Isn't there any method to avoid writing code?

Comment: Have a look at first link, you may need to update VS and Install latest Azure Tools